# Changing a span field to an input field for updating information

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I am creating a way to edit dynamic content. I found a question on here that got me started in terms of changing text (spans in my case) into input fields.

Currently, I can't figure out the following issue. When you click "Edit" (on the right side) the input fields replace the span (this is what I want), but when when you click outside of the input the input fields add new span fields instead of replacing the input fields.

I am wanting the styling and the fields to constantly stay in their original place.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```js
var projID = '';

 //Obtaining ID and Editing the projects
 $(document.body).on('click', '.recEdit', '[data-editable]', function() {
  projID = $(this).parent().data('recid');
  console.log('Project ID is..... ' + projID);

  var $el = $(this).parent().children().find('span');

  var $input = $('<input/>').val( $el.text() );
  $el.replaceWith( $input );

  var save = function(){
   var $p = $('<span data-editable class="recBaseFormat" />').text( $input.val() );
   $input.replaceWith( $p );
  };

  /**
    We're defining the callback with `one`, because we know that
    the element will be gone just after that, and we don't want 
    any callbacks leftovers take memory. 
    Next time `p` turns into `input` this single callback 
    will be applied again.
  */
  $input.one('blur', save).focus();
 });
```

```css
.recentProjectCont {
 width: 98%;
 height: 85px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 10px 0;
 margin: 0 10px;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
}
.recentProjectImg {
 width: 100px;
 height: 85px;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}
.recentProjectImg img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
}
.recProjInfoCont {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 80%;
 height: 100%;
 margin-left: 20px;
}
.recInfoCont1, .recInfoCont2 {
 height: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}
.recInfoCont1 {
 width: 40%;
}
.recInfoCont2 {
 width: 52%;
 text-align: right;
}
.recBaseFormat, .projectViews {
 letter-spacing: .1rem;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 color: #2f2f2f;
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.recProjName {
 font-size: 1.1rem;
 font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
}
.recInfoStat, .projectViews {
 font-size: .7rem;
 font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}
.recEdit {
 position: absolute;
 top: 20%;
 left: 97%;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="recentProjectCont">
 <div class="recProjInfoCont">
  <div class="recInfoCont1">
   <span class="recProjName recBaseFormat" data-editable>Name</span>
   <span class="recInfoStat recBaseFormat recAlt" data-editable>Alt</span>
   <span class="recInfoStat recBaseFormat recCat" data-editable>Category</span>
  </div>
  <div class="recInfoCont2">
   <span class="recInfoStat recBaseFormat" data-editable>Status</span>
   <span class="recInfoStat recBaseFormat" data-editable>Creator</span>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="recEdit">Edit</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Code appears to be working, the problem is that this line: `var $el = $(this).parent().children().find('span');` is only going to target the last `span` element within the container. That's why no matter which `input` you change the text in, only the last `input` gets replaced with the `span` containing that text. Look into using jQuery's [each method](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop through each span.

Comment: @APAD1 Any ideas on what I could change it to?

Comment: Updated my comment, basically you need to loop over each `span`.

Comment: Have you considered using the `contenteditable` attribute?

Comment: @APAD1 What would I use as the selector though? I tried putting in `span`, but this then gets all the spans. To reduce the amount of code I put in my question, I eliminated some of the html. The html is made up of looped results, so what you see in the html is that x 10. That is why I was using this `$(this).parent().children().find('span')`

Comment: @Barmar Never heard of it. I will have to check it out. Is it a native HtML attribute, I'm guessing?

Comment: Yes, it is. Some say it's poor style, others recommend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code could definitely be optimized, but it should get you going in the right direction. There were a few issues with your code. The issue I mentioned above, which is that your selector was only targeting the last `span` element within the parent element. We can solve that by using the [each method](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop over every `span` within the parent. Another issue is that you were losing the classes for your spans when you were replacing them with inputs. I've solved that by saving a list of classes for each span before replacing them with an `input` so that they can be reapplied when they are converted back to `spans`. Finally, you were firing the `save` function for all inputs on blur of any input, meaning that the user would only be able to edit one span and then when they clicked out, all inputs would have been converted back. Instead, now it will only convert back when you unfocus each specific input.

```js
var projID = '';

//Obtaining ID and Editing the projects
$(document.body).on('click', '.recEdit', '[data-editable]', function() {
 projID = $(this).parent().data('recid');
 console.log('Project ID is..... ' + projID);

 $(this).parent().children().find('span').each(function() {
  var classList = $(this).attr('class');
  $input = $('<input/>').val($(this).text());

  $(this).replaceWith($input);
  $input.on('blur',function() {
   $(this).replaceWith('<span data-editable class="' + classList + '">' + $(this).val() + '</span>');
  });
 });
});
```

```css
.recentProjectCont {
 width: 98%;
 height: 85px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 10px 0;
 margin: 0 10px;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
}
.recentProjectImg {
 width: 100px;
 height: 85px;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}
.recentProjectImg img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
}
.recProjInfoCont {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 80%;
 height: 100%;
 margin-left: 20px;
}
.recInfoCont1, .recInfoCont2 {
 height: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}
.recInfoCont1 {
 width: 40%;
}
.recInfoCont2 {
 width: 52%;
 text-align: right;
}
.recBaseFormat, .projectViews {
 letter-spacing: .1rem;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 color: #2f2f2f;
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.recProjName {
 font-size: 1.1rem;
 font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
}
.recInfoStat, .projectViews {
 font-size: .7rem;
 font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}
.recEdit {
 position: absolute;
 top: 20%;
 left: 97%;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="recentProjectCont">
 <div class="recProjInfoCont">
  <div class="recInfoCont1">
   <span class="recProjName recBaseFormat" data-editable>Name</span>
   <span class="recInfoStat recBaseFormat recAlt" data-editable>Alt</span>
   <span class="recInfoStat recBaseFormat recCat" data-editable>Category</span>
  </div>
  <div class="recInfoCont2">
   <span class="recInfoStat recBaseFormat" data-editable>Status</span>
   <span class="recInfoStat recBaseFormat" data-editable>Creator</span>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="recEdit">Edit</div>
</div>
```

Finally, as others have mentioned, another option would be to use the [contenteditable attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable) on your spans. This is an HTML solution for editing HTML elements that are not editable by default. It essentially does the same thing you're trying to do with Javascript, but it's much cleaner. It also has [very good browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable). One drawback to this solution would be that it will not be immediately clear to the user that the element is editable like it would be with an actual button that says "Edit." But there are some solutions for that as well.

```html
<span contenteditable="true">You can edit me</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and explanation. This is perfect.

Comment: Random question. Let's say the user types in text and realizes they want the original back, do you know if there would be a way to clear the changes?

Comment: One possibility would be to store the initial values in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or in a [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) when the user clicks "Edit" and then you would need another button called "Reset" or something to that effect and then you could restore the initial value from `localStorage` or the `cookie`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use juste the `contenteditable` attribute toggle each click !